# Получаеться расположить div'ы по сетке, но не работает если поменять их на img CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css3, img, css-grid

Как правильно будет сделать в случае, если нужно вставить изображения вместо цветного блока?

```css
.blog__slider-content-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 12px;
  outline: purple 1px solid;
  width: 407px;
  height: 267px;
}

.blog__slider-content-image-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  background: tomato;
}

.blog__slider-content-image-2 {
  background: royalblue;
}

.blog__slider-content-image-3 {
  background: royalblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog__slider-content">
  <div class="blog__slider-content-images">
    <div class="blog__slider-content-image-1"></div>
    <div class="blog__slider-content-image-2"></div>
    <div class="blog__slider-content-image-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если я меняю `div` на `img` то не работает.

Как корректно делать в данном случае?

Comment: Как `background-image` и `cover` нельзя?

Comment: @NoSkill  background-image вроде же при слайдере не применяется?

Comment: а что это за слайдер? у меня, например, прекрасно применяется слайдер на background-image... и в зависимости от desktop и mobile, картинки меняются на другие.

Comment: @NoSkill ну вроде по правилам. background вроде при логотипах, кнопках обычно используют

Comment: А смысл? Картинки целесообразно применять только там, где их можно ЗАХОТЕТЬ скачать по правому клику. В остальных случаях какие могут быть правила...? Для кого? Зачем?

Comment: Да услышал где то

Comment: @NoSkill `Картинки целесообразно применять только там, где их можно ЗАХОТЕТЬ скачать по правому клику` Вы это сами придумали? Зачем Вы вводите человека в заблуждение, когда сами не разбираетесь в том что говорите.

Comment: @Vasily Жду конструктивного коментария. Пока ваш коментраий ни о чём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойства, которые я добавил что бы это заработало:

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Рабочий пример:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.blog__slider-content-images {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 12px;
  width: 407px;
  height: 267px;
  outline: purple 1px solid;
}

.blog__slider-content-image-1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog__slider-content">
  <div class="blog__slider-content-images">
    <img class="blog__slider-content-image-1" src="https://picsum.photos/400"/>
    <img class="blog__slider-content-image-2" src="https://picsum.photos/400"/>
    <img class="blog__slider-content-image-3" src="https://picsum.photos/400"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Вам нужно будет только отрегулировать размеры картинок под "ячейки" (grid'ы), либо "ячейки" под размеры картинок (как это сейчас).*